# Leak caused by fread

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm profiling code of a game I wrote and I'm wondering how it is possible that the following snippet causes an heap increase of 4kb (I'm profiling with Heapshot Analysis of Xcode) every time it is executed:

```
u8 WorldManager::versionOfMap(FILE *file)
{
  char magic[4];
  u8 version;

  fread(magic, 4, 1, file); <-- this is the line
  fread(&version,1,1,file);
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

  return version;
}
```

According to the profiler the highlighted line allocates 4.00Kb of memory with a `malloc` every time the function is called, memory which is never released. This thing seems to happen with other calls to `fread` around the code, but this was the most eclatant one.

Is there anything trivial I'm missing? Is it something internal I shouldn't care about?

Just as a note: I'm profiling it on an iPhone and it's compiled as release (`-O2`).

Comment: what happens when you change it to `fread(magic, 1, 4, file);` ?

Comment: Have you checked for read errors (e.g. with `ferror(file)`)?

Comment: another point: check the result of the `fread` call !

Comment: Just tried but the same thing happens. I don't think that swapping the count with the size could cause a similar issue though, the function `fread` itself doesn't even know the kind of pointer it will use to store data..

Comment: @Jack replace it with `fseek (file, 4, SEEK_CUR);` and see what happens...

Comment: @Yahia you mean `fseek (file, -4, SEEK_CUR);`?

Comment: So if you create a simple test application which just reads from a file say, 10000 times, it will increase memory usage by 40MB? Otherwise, it *is* being freed, and you're just not seeing it. So try that and see what happens :)

Comment: @Jack no... I mean move the file pointer 4 bytes ahead with `fseek (file, 4, SEEK_CUR);` instead of the `fread` call that allocates 4K.

Comment: @Yahia I can do it but I would like to check magic against a fixed magic number I chose for the file format. Even if it's not mandatory I would like to know why memory leaks :)

Comment: @Jack I understand... this is just a "diagnostic change"... if the leak disappears with this change or perhaps it then happens on the next line (i.e. the now first `fread`) then this tells us where to look...

Comment: @Yahia: curiously the leak persists and it is set on `fseek` line, with a 100% of accuracy. I'm starting to think that this profiler is just telling tales..

Comment: @Jack just some speculation - the first access to the `file` causes the system to allocate a minimum of 1 memory page (usually 4K)... IF this is the case THEN this is normal and will be released somewhere down the road (usually when closing the `file`).

Comment: @Jack the structure `FILE` holds an internal buffer in most C runtime implementations I know...

Comment: @Yahia thanks for your help, actually the `FILE*` is closed quite soon after that function, I'll try to investigate it further!

Comment: You can test @Yahia's theory by verifying that the memory is released when you call `fclose()`.

Comment: Do you `fclose()` the file? The CRT will allocate an internal buffer for each file you open (most likely at the first `fread()`). If you forget to `fclose()` the file the buffer will not be released and to the profiler it will seem that the first `fread()` you perform will leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're describing is really happening and your code has no bugs elsewhere, it is a bug in the implementation, I think.

More likely I think, is the possibility that you don't close the file.   Stdio streams use buffering by default if the device is non-interactive, and the buffer is allocated either at the time the file is opened or when I/O is performed.   While only one buffer should be allocated, you can certainly leak the buffer by forgetting to close the file.   But certainly, closing the file should free the buffer.   Don't forget to check the value returned by `fclose`.

Supposing for the sake of argument that you are correctly closing the file there are a couple of other nits in your code which won't be causing this problem but I'll mention anyway.

First your `fread` call reads an object having one member of size 4.   You actually have an object having 4 members of size 1.   In other words the numeric arguments to `fread` are swapped.   This makes a difference only in the meaning of the return value (important in the case of a partial read).

Second, while your first call to `fread` correctly hard-codes the size of `char` as 1 (in C, that is the definition of 'size'), it's probably better stylistically to use `sizeof(u8)` in the second call to `fread`.

If the idea that this really is a memory leak is a correct interpretation (and there aren't any bugs elsewhere) then you may be able to work around the problem by turning off the stdio buffering for this particular file:

```
bool WorldManager::versionOfMap(FILE *file, bool *is_first_file_io, u8 *version)
{
  char magic[4];
  bool ok = false;
  if (*is_first_file_io) 
  {
    // we ignore failure of this call
    setvbuf(file, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    *is_first_file_io = false;
  }

  if (sizeof(magic) == fread(magic, 1, sizeof(magic), file) 
      && 1 == fread(version, sizeof(*version), 1, file))
  {
      ok = true;
  }
  if (-1 == fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET))
  {
      return false;
  }
  else
  {
      return ok && 0 == memcmp(magic, EXPECTED_MAGIC, sizeof(magic));
  }
}
```

Even if we're going with the hypothesis that this really is a bug, and the leak is real, it is well worth condensing your code to the smallest possible example that still demonstrates the problem.   If doing that reveals the true bug, you win.   Otherwise, you will need the minimal example to report the bug in the implementation.